# Does tung oil odor last as long as linseed oil odor?

Tags: wood-finishing, wood-finish

One week after two applications of linseed oil on a desk tabletop, followed by rubbing and wiping, the odor still fills the room, despite reasonable ventilation.

It's not particularly unpleasant, but it's strong and the bottle (Ikea's Behandla brand) lists some additional ingredients that I am concerned would qualify as VOCs, and hence I'd rather not breathe it.

Tung oil is an option for the amateur woodworker. (Boiled) linseed oil turned out to require much more patience than I have: The bottle lists applying daily, weekly, then monthly for a year for proper curing.

This [answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/39931/38937) suggests that I can indeed seal the wood with tung oil after having applied linseed oil. My two applications were on the generous side (with a brush), but the wood still feels dry to the touch.

Does the odor of tung oil disappear a week or two after application? Would it seal in the odor of linseed oil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tung oil also leaves a lingering smell, [quoting](http://www.woodworkdetails.com/knowledge/finishing/tung-oil):

> Tung oil produces a mildly disagreeable odor for a few days after it
>   is applied. This odor lessens with time, however some find that it
>   continues for quite some time afterwards. If the tung oil is to be
>   coated with some other finish such as wax, shellac, lacquer or
>   polyurethane, this smell is no longer noticeable.